# Multiple column means by name in R

Tags: r

I feel like this should be easy, but I'm at a loss.

I have a matrix with multiple morphometric headers. There are a lot, so I have assigned names rather than calling the column by number. I want to get the means of multiple columns all in one line.

1. I can get one at a time (and I get the value, same for `VTL` and some other elements I have)

   `mean(mydata[,"STL"],na.rm=TRUE)`
2. I can also get multiple vectors side by side:

   `mydata[,c("STL","VTL")]`

But when I put (2) into (1) I get:

```
"Warning message:
    In mean.default(mydata[, c("SVL", "VTL")], na.rm = TRUE) :
      argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"
```

What is going on here? Is there a way to return multiples means at once?

Comment: Try `colMeans` instead of `mean`

Comment: That won't work as I have some columns which are not numerical, guess I could just parse them out if I can't figure this other way out.

Comment: If you don't care much about warnings, you could also vectorize this as in `colMeans(df^1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the numeric columns and than use colMeans?

```
d=data.frame(a=1:10,b=letters[1:10],c=1:10)
nums <- sapply(d, is.numeric)
colMeans(d[ , nums])
```

Comment: That's funny cause I was just writing that answer and got distracted, even the example data was the same :)

Comment: Much appreciated! Just needed to exclude the NAs and it came out perfect.